# Any way to define total character limit in json schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I need to restrict my json files to a certain filesize. I have all the properties defined and requireds required, but how do I limit the entire thing?

Comment: Why do you need to restrict file size?

Comment: @Ether It's a technical requirement of the service where the information is being stored. It will not accept data larger than a certain number of kilobytes, so I wish to restrict it in the schema. That way, I do not need to constantly check the size somehow, or remind other developers to do so.

Answer (score 1):

JSON schema does not have any way to enforce total size of a complex instance.